# Is there a way to use a motion with a register?

Tags: vim, neovim

lets say I have a 5 in the register `"`,
I want to be able to use the content of that register to move 5 words. An example

```
5w
```

would be

```
[some way to read the register]w
```

is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No other than:

```
:exec 'norm! '.@".'w'
```

This works by

- `@x` returns content of `x` register, so in this case `@"` returns content of `"` register
- generating string (`.` is concatenation operator in VimL) that contains `norm! <val of " reg>w`
- `:norm!` will execute given string as a operations in normal mode (ignoring any user mappings, which is `!` doing)
- `:exec` will execute given string as it would be a command-line mode command

Comment: Some explanation might be beneficial. We encourage it over at [vi.se]